# Is encoding/json Marshal a JSON alphabetically by default?

Tags: json, go

```
func sort(input string) string {
    var data interface{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &data)
    ret, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    return string(ret)
}
```

just like code above, if i Unmarshal a json string into interface, then Marshal it to json string, is this json ret sort by alphabetically default?

seems like encoding/json Marshal will sort keys by alphabetically default, but is there any doc or article prove this?

thanks

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal, map keys are sorted.

Answer (score 1):

According to the functions documentation:

Map values encode as JSON objects. The map's key type must either be a string, an integer type, or implement encoding.TextMarshaler. The map keys are sorted and used as JSON object keys by applying the following rules, subject to the UTF-8 coercion described for string values above:

- keys of any string type are used directly
- encoding.TextMarshalers are marshaled
- integer keys are converted to strings